# Object not spinning in place when using Z rotation

Tags: rendering, mesh, transforms, keyframes, shape-keys

[image]So I had a bunch of meshes to make a low poly character that I joined all using Ctrl+J but when I rotate the single mesh on the z axis its spins in a circle instead of just spinning in place.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your object's origin is not at its center. To fix this:

Click that object and then click
*Object > Set Origin > Origin to Center Of Mass (Surface)*